# All possible permutations of dice rolls

Tags: java, math, permutation

I want to write a program that simulates the following: I have 6 dice, and I roll with some dice every time.

When I don't roll with a die, I just assume that I rolled 0 with that.

I want to list all the possible variations I can get this way. A few examples:

1,2,4,6,0,1

3,5,1,0,0,4

6,6,4,2,0,0
etc.

Any ideas on how to do this?
(I am using Java, but of course, I'm only interested in the general concept.)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Look at the "Related" section at the right. There are already dozens of questions asking for this.

Comment: Of course I did search before I asked the question, but I couldn't find anything like this.

Comment: As for the code, I didn't get far after I realized that my original concept was extremely stupid, I was just thinking since then.
(originally my code just subtracted 1 from each dice's value, until it was 0, and then it went to the next one)

Comment: FYI, *dice* is plural.  The singular form is *die*.  Perhaps this is not programming related, but if your software has a user interface, you should present the user with the right words. :-)

Comment: Thanks, another thing I learned today.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a well understood problem, but the OP has shown no thought or effort whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive method, keeping track of depth:
EDIT, maybe this method would be better:

```
class Main {
    public static void roll(String s, int depth) {
        if(depth == 0)
            System.out.println(s.substring(1));
        else
            for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
                roll(s + "," + i, depth - 1);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        roll("", 6); //2nd parameter > 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I'll accept your answer because I was looking for a recursive solution, but also thanks to all the others!

Answer (score 3):

Since you specifically asked for *"only the general concept"*, here are two general approaches, either:

- Use a 6-level nested for-loop for just do an exhaustive enumeration of all possible rolls between `0-6` (more efficient)
- Just use 1 for-loop to generate all numbers between `0-66666`, and discard any numbers that contain `7, 8, 9`; and then print the numbers with some formatted padding, and commas (cleaner code to look at if you don't care about the small efficiency difference)

Comment: Thanks! I thought of the 6 level nested loop first, but I thought that there must be a more convenient solution. (I still wonder if this could be done with recursion somehow.)

I think I'll go with the second, great idea, thanks!

Comment: The first method is very messy, and will be very hard to modify/update in the future. The second method is *extremely* inefficient.

Comment: Yeah, but I only need it for this particular problem, so it would do fine. Altough the recursive method is nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Just for elegance sake, I would write a recursive method that calls loops through 0-7 for a given index then itself to initialize the next index.

It could then initialize an array or abritrary size.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Python implementation.

This is when you just print.

```
def PrintAllPerms(n, str_):
    if (n == 0):
        print str_
    else:
        for i in ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]:
            str_ = str_ + i
            PrintAllPerms(n-1, str_)
            str_ = str_[:-1]

PrintAllPerms(2,"")
```

This is when you want to return the whole permutation.

```
def PrintAllPerms(n, arr, str_):
    if (n == 0):
        arr.append(str_)
        return arr
    else:
        for i in ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]:
            str_ = str_ + i
            arr = PrintAllPerms(n-1,arr,str_)
            str_ = str_[:-1]
        return arr

PrintAllPerms(2,[],"")
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public class DiceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] dice = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        for (int i : dice) {
            for (int j : dice) {
                System.out.println("Printing dice values : " + i + " " + j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some context to your answer.